# Extract Multiline Data between 2 sentences using Regex in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, multiline

I have this data

```
Date = 10

data = ["""Number of Days are 4 days : 

john: 12

jade: 452

kent: 3542

Number of Days are 10 days : 

john: 34

jade: 765

kent: 9473"""]
```

I need data from of john , jade and kent from 10 days and not 4 days as saved in the variable 'Date = 10' . can anyone suggest any regex formula in python 3.X to solve this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issue are you facing with your current solution?

Comment: and what are you expecting as result? like the whole string after 10 days, only the data from each person etc.

Comment: @Flying_whale : i am not good with regex yet. i am a newbie... need help with regex formula

Comment: @Deathshadow : i am ok with both outputs ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit complicated to do this with new lines and it would be much easier with any character as split but this is what I got:

```
import re
Date = "10"
regex = r"(?<=Number of Days are %s days : \n\n)(.+\n{0,2})+?((?=Number of Days)|(?=$))" % (Date) 
test_str = ("""Number of Days are 4 days : 

john: 12

jade: 452

kent: 3542

Number of Days are 10 days : 

john: 34

jade: 765

kent: 9473

Number of Days are 11 days : 

john: 34

jade: 765

kent: 9473""")

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    print (matches.group())
```

My Regex is the following:

```
r"(?<=Number of Days are %s days : \n\n)(.+\n{0,2})+?((?=Number of Days)|(?=$))"
```

First part:

```
(?<=Number of Days are %s days : \n\n)
```

This looks if there is your search string `Number of Days are %s days` `%s` is referencing on your variable Date

Second part:

```
(.+\n{0,2})+
```

looks for any character with 0 or 2 new lines at the end.

Third part:

```
?((?=Number of Days)|(?=$))
```

this looks if there is any `Number of Days` or it is the end of the string and stops the second part from getting more matches if that's true.

Comment: @suyash999 please accept it as answer. Thank you :)

Comment: i need some additional help...  i am applying this regex on the Email message which is downloaded as string in text/plain format into a variable... the regex is not working on it... but if i copy the email message completely and paste  it in my code as a string in a  variable, then the regex is working. I am not able to understand this issue..

Comment: @suyash999 Did you debug it and looked if the variable contains the right text? Maybe you get some additional characters while getting it from your Email

Comment: I checked it... i had printed the email message on the screen from the variable... copied the same message and pasted in another variable in another code having the same regex... the only issue is that its not working on the email message , but working perfectly if i copied it any other variable.

Comment: @suyash999 could you give me the example that I can see it myself?